# Consume a GeoJSON service from GeoServer in QGIS 3.4?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, geojson, wfs

It seems there has been an update to the way QGIS consumes GeoJSON files in version 3.4x

At 2.18.x, a WFS service with GeoJSON output from GeoServer such as:

https://server.org/geoserver/datastore/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=datastore:dps_boundary&maxFeatures=1000&outputFormat=application%2Fjson

...can be added simply as a 'vector > file' or 'protocol > geojson'.

However, at v. 3.4.x, the GeoJSON doesn't work by either a file or a protocol (there are two types of GeoJSON in this list, neither work), with the error "Invalid Layer"

Has anyone else noticed this change or have any advice as to how to work with GeoServer WFS services with GeoJSON output?

Comment: Why not use a WFS layer?

Comment: @IanTurton we provide data to a 3rd party vendor (their request) via GeoJSON, and I want to test it in QGIS.

Comment: This might be a local problem with your QGIS installment, I just tested this on mine using both `GeoJSON` and `HTTP/HTTPS/FTP` and it works fine. This is the url i tested with: ```http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ne/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=ne%3Ane&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson``` which is simply what i got when i used the GeoJson option in layer preview. You should test on other computers and might want to fix or reinstall QGIS. I am using Win 10 with QGIS 3.4.6 and Geoserver 2.15.1 all installed on the same machine.

Comment: The link is giving me 404 not found

Comment: @neogeomat my URL is not real, the other one is internal (localhost) only, so you won't be able to test them.